# How to import CSV with custom format in Laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, laravel-10

I'm creating a CSV import feature in Laravel using the [laravel excel package](https://laravel-excel.com/). I have CSV data with a format like this:

```
16070251039000021#16070224021150003#"JOHN DOE"#"P"#"1990-03-11"#"SUNGSANG"#"S"#"0"#"KAMPUNG BARU JELITIK SUNGAILIAT"#000#005#"KEPULAUAN BANGKA BELITUNG"#"BANGKA"#"SUNGAILIAT"#1901011001#"SUNGAILIAT"#1
```

From the data format above, I want to retrieve data like this: `getVillageId(KEPULAUAN BANGKA BELITUNG, BANGKA BARAT, TEMPILANG, AIR LINTANG)`

I have coded as below:

**TpsController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Master;

use App\Models\Tps;
use App\Imports\TpsImport;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class TpsController extends Controller
{
    public function import(Request $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'file' => 'required|mimetypes:text/plain,text/csv',
            ],[
                'file.required' => 'The file field is required.',
                'file.mimes' => 'The file must be a file of type: csv.',
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => $validator->messages()->all()[0]
                ], 422);
            }

            Excel::import(new TpsImport, $request->file('file'), null);

            DB::commit();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Data imported successfully'
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $th->getMessage()
            ], 422);
        }
    }

}
```

**TpsImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Tps;
use App\Traits\Location;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;

class TpsImport implements OnEachRow, WithBatchInserts, WithCustomCsvSettings
{
    use Location;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        //Format data: 16070251039000021#190501113101120003#"JOHN DOE"#"L"#"1984-04-04"#"TEMPILANG"#"S"#"0"#"JALAN CEMPAKA"#003#005#"KEPULAUAN BANGKA BELITUNG"#"BANGKA BARAT"#"TEMPILANG"#1905052007#"AIR LINTANG"#5
        
        $row = array_map(function($item) {
            return str_replace('"', '', $item);
        }, $row->toArray());

        //getVillageId(KEPULAUAN BANGKA BELITUNG, BANGKA BARAT, TEMPILANG, AIR LINTANG);
        $area_id = $this->getVillageId($row[13], $row[14], $row[15], $row[17]);

        //check if data already exists
        $tps = Tps::where([
            'area_id' => $area_id,
            'name' => $row[18],
        ])->first();

        if ($tps) {
            return;
        }

        $tps = Tps::create([
            'area_id' => $area_id,
            'name' => $row[18],
        ]);
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => "#"
        ];
    }
}
```

**Location.php**

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Traits;

trait Location
{

    public function getVillageId($province = null, $city = null, $district = null, $village = null)
    {
        $village = \App\Models\Village::where([
            'province_name' => $province,
            'city_name' => $city,
            'district_name' => $district,
            'name' => $village,
        ])->first();
        
        if ($village) {
            return $village->id;
        }
 
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

When I run it, I get an error message like this: Undefined array key 13

How to create a CSV import feature with a special format in Laravel?